# Is Cost of Living overstated?

Tags: salary, rent

Cost of living is a major factor in people's decisions: where to live, how much salary is needed for comparable lifestyles, and so on. But I was thinking the other day, that CoL might be overemphasized as a cost, given how big a chunk rent is.

High rent places are usually also high property value places. Given the tax incentives, it seems like a good long term idea to grab a house, so if we assume you have the option of working and buying a house in a high CoL or a low CoL city, I think you'd prefer the high cost. Because essentially, after 30 years, you'd have a million dollar house vs a quarter million dollar house. You've captured three quarters of a million dollars in rent, given my napkin math hypothetical.

Do cost of living calculators generally account for this rent capture? Or am I missing something and they don't need to?

Comment: Are you citing a particular cost of living index?

Comment: I usually just use something like salary.com or bankrate. Would it help to construct specifics?

Comment: Buying instead of renting is a good way for people in high tax brackets to avoid taxes. Buying a house gives you "imputed rent" - money saved on rent, which isn't taxed. If you just put that money in the stock market and used the returns towards renting a house, that's money you do have to pay tax on.

Comment: You do understand that "high property value" means "houses cost a lot to BUY".

Answer (score 6):

New York City is high cost-of-living, and I have absolutely no clue why people live there.  It's a tough place, and the taxes are oppressive.  People buy a studio apartment for $150,000 [that has 175 square feet](http://www.nypost.com/p/news/local/manhattan/cozy_crazy_couple_makes_tight_studio_R15ToNFTaJE3c17zkw4efP) (that's not a typo) plus a $700/month maintenance fee that continues *after* the mortgage is paid off.  And that's just what the fee is now.

Our rental house (which used to be our primary residence) at 1,300 square feet has a (15-year) mortgage payment of about $800, and $1,000 per year in property taxes.  And my area isn't particularly *low* cost-of-living.

High cost-of-living is just that.  More money flies out the door just for the privilege of living there.  You make good investments with real estate by buying property at a good price in a good location.  Those deals are everywhere, but in high CoL locations you're probably more susceptible to price fluctuations which will trap you in your property if your mortgage goes underwater.

Anyway, that's a long way of saying that I don't buy your recommendation to get property in high CoL areas.  There are desirable low CoL places to live, too.

Comment: NYC is a hotbed of activity.  If you can stand the heat, it is a great kitchen.  That said, the CPI in Manhattan is just plain insane.

Comment: For another $210,000 and a post-inflation rate of return of 4% in the stock market, you can cover that $700/mo. So it's a $360,000 apartment. And that probably includes all the utilities and heat. So what's that to someone working Wall Street? I mean the mid-range guys, not just the million-dollars-a-day guys. Maybe two years' salary? That's not a totally horrible deal for a studio apartment.

Comment: NYC != Manhattan. Very few people choose to raise families in Manhattan, given the absurd costs. The exception is if you happen to be related to someone whose rent is artificially low due to rent control law. The Queens, Brooklyn and Staten Island are all parts of NYC and have a much more reasonable cost of living. I grew up in Queens, and many of our neighbors worked on Wall Street, or other Manhattan based businesses.

Comment: if you live in NYC you understand why people are willing to pay so much :).

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is a strong correlation between CPI (Consumer Price Index) and housing value appreciation.

Take, for example, New York City which has the highest CPI in the US.  A great deal of the CPI number is skewed by Manhattan.  One can live in Brooklyn or Queens and avoid some of NYC's high CPI.  I would say that housing appreciation occurs because of the human activity in the area.  That same human activity is what drives the CPI.  There are other contributing factors, like limits on economies of scale.  You simply cannot set down a Super Walmart in much of NYC, so goods are distributed over a larger number of stores.  (Sure, NYC is a port city, but the goods are distributed within the city by trucks.)

The San Francisco Bay Area is another high CPI area in the US.  Here, as well, it is the location that draws people.  While NYC is mostly about economic activity, the SF Bay Area is a mix of the draw of a great location and the economic activity that occurs due to the large number of people living there.  I know of a house in Oakland that sold for approximately $350k, in 2004/05.  It was located not too far from the "Killing Fields," as they were known locally.  It was not the worst neighborhood in Oakland, but it was not very far from it.  This was for a shabby, single-story unit which I believe had 5 (maybe 6) rooms.  That is a lot of money for a house that required a lot of attention and was in a bad neighborhood.  I have no idea how the housing market is after the housing bubble, but the higher value areas had the most room to fall and many of them fell hard.

Ultimately, it is supply and demand that determines the CPI and housing values.  This supply and demand is determined by the human activity in the area and some practical considerations regarding the area.

A final note: If we are talking about a primary residence, it should not necessarily be looked at as an investment.  First and foremost, it is a necessity.  Second, if you need to hire people for the maintenance and/or upgrades, that will eat into your gains.  Contractors are not cheap, especially where they are in high demand.  Finally, the tax incentive is actually not that great.  Sure, you take what you can get, but its impact is relatively marginal.

Comment: "I do not believe there is a strong correlation between CPI (Consumer Price Index) and housing value appreciation." Isn't Rent or rent equivalent a large part of the CPI?

Comment: @jldugger Correct, housing costs are a significant part of the CPI.  That statement still bothers me somewhat.  However, we are not necessarily dealing with symmetric properties.  That is, housing is a large part of the CPI and thus increases in the cost of housing lead to increases in the CPI.  I am arguing that increases in the CPI do not necessarily lead to increase in the cost of housing.  Rather, it is the human activity in these areas that leads to these increases.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Upstate NY. It's a great, reasonable cost place to live -- provided that you have a job.

In NYC, there are probably a few hundred jobs with duties similar to mine in a 45-minute radius. Upstate, there may be 5-6.

Answer (score 1):

> after 30 years, you'd have a million dollar house vs a quarter million dollar house. You've captured three quarters of a million dollars in rent, given my napkin math hypothetical.

As I figure the math, a 250,000 house appreciating to a million dollar house in 30 years requires a sustained ~4.9% appreciation every year--seems unrealistic. The historical rate of inflation, on average, has been closer to 3-3.5%; a 3% appreciation would give a final value of $589k.  This also doesn't taken into account the idea that you may have bought a property during a housing bubble, and so then you *wouldn't* get 3% year-over-year returns.

But also, in terms of "capturing rent", you are not factoring in necessary or possible costs that renting doesn't have:  mortgage interest and insurance, maintenance, property tax, insurance, buying and selling associated fees, and, importantly, opportunity costs (in that the money not tied up in the house could be invested elsewhere).

So it is not such a slam dunk as you make it out.  Many use the [NY Times buy/rent calculator](http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/business/buy-rent-calculator.html) to compare renting vs. buying.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that cost of living is related to ensuring greater appreciation of assets over time, especially over a 30 year window.

The importance of regional differences in cost of living to anyone's decision-making *should* be weighted by the percentage of their income spent on indexed items.  That is, for people who spend 35%, or even 50% of their salary on indexed items, regional variances in cost of living are far more important than for people who spend 10% of their salaries on these items.  Essentially, as income goes up, the significance of cost of living goes down.

See http://macromon.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/how-u-s-income-groups-get-squeezed-by-food-prices/ for a pretty picture of the relevance of cost of living across income groups (for food & gas, which are often not included in indexes due to volatility).

So, if you are wondering whether cost of living is overstated, perhaps it's because you are in an income group that doesn't need to worry about it as much.  Whether it's overstated or not will depend on how much one makes and spends.

Comment: A place like San Francisco has good pay, but an expensive cost-of-living. If you can keep your lifestyle modest, though - mostly by housing needs down and not eating out too much - living there may be a good way to save money for a future in some place less expensive (e.g. if you want to settle down and have kids somewhere). I'm sure that can be technically considered as some sort of arbitrage...

Answer (score 0):

You mention:

> High rent places are usually also high
>   property value places. Given the tax
>   incentives, it seems like a good long
>   term idea to grab a house, so if we
>   assume you have the option of working
>   and buying a house in a high CoL or a
>   low CoL city, I think you'd prefer the
>   high cost. Because essentially, after
>   30 years, you'd have a million dollar
>   house vs a quarter million dollar
>   house. You've captured three quarters
>   of a million dollars in rent, given my
>   napkin math hypothetical.

I think you're forgetting about some of the associated costs with "owning" a home, including:

1. More expensive homes typically require you to pay more taxes. [Property Taxes vary state by state](http://www.nytimes.com/2007/04/10/business/11leonhardt-avgproptaxrates.html), but are almost always a % of the value of a home. Higher property value, higher property taxes.
2. Assuming you don't have the capital required to buy an expensive home outright (and from your analysis above, I don't think you do) you have to pay interest on the debt that you end up taking out to pay for a home.  The more expensive a home, the more interest you will have to pay overall. Say, for the sake of argument, with current interest rates, you can buy a house for $200K with a 30 year mortgage. But with interest payments the overall net present value is $400k. If you live in a high cost of living area, if you buy a $400K house instead of a 200K house, with equal borrowing costs you'll end up paying the equivalent of $800K over time.

Comment: Even if you have the money to buy a house outright, if the house had been less you could have had that money earning interest in a savings account. In other words, when house prices are high, living in one costs you lots of money.